# JavaScript Programming variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm using a JSON array that has 38 fields and I have to sum each of the fields.

I've tried a small sample set to test how and I'm running into a problem:

I have variables called field1, field2, .... So I figured out how to create them but it looks like it sees the variables as text not the values inside them.

```
test1 = [[36,1500,2,3,4],[36,15,2,7,8],[36,3000,4,5,6],[36,8,7,6,15]]

for (var i = 0; i < test1.length;  i++) {  //get each array

      for (var n = 0; n < 5;  n++) {   //get each  item in the array

        var theField = "field" + n;

        theField = theField +test1[i][n];  //This fails

        field2 = field2 + test1[i][2];  //This works
```

If I use field + n to create the variable, the sum value at the end is 0,

if I call field2 = field2 + test1[i][2] at the end of the loop I have the sum for the third value in each array. However I have to hard code field1 -> field38.

Comment: Are you looking for the total sum of all the elements in all the arrays, or the sum of each sub-array?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a variable to hold the name of the other variable.  This is the wrong idea.  You should show the rest of your code (including your named variables) as you are heading down the wrong path.

Comment: I have an array that holds many arrays, I filter the real ones by the first element to get all 2017 records, then each sub-array has 38 elements in it, I need to get the sum of all the  2nd elements, 3rd element, 4th  elements...

Comment: Are you adding 2nd+3rd+4th element together (e.g., arr1[1]+arr1[2]…arr1[n]) to get the sum?  Or are you doing a sum by the index?  arr1[2]+arr2[2]…arrN[2]

Comment: @BillChappell see the answer below, which addresses both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sum by Array

```js
let data = [
  [36, 1500, 2, 3, 4],
  [36, 15, 2, 7, 8],
  [99, 99, 99, 99 ,99], // fake data
  [36, 3000, 4, 5, 6],
  [36, 8, 7, 6, 15]
]

// only pull records with 36 as value of first element
let filtered = data.filter(arr=>arr[0]==36)

// iterate over each array and sum elements at index 1...end
let sum = filtered.map(([_,...arr]) => arr.reduce((sum, val) => sum += +val, 0))

console.log(sum)
```

1. Filter the data for what you want based on the first element (stored in `filtered`)
2. Iterate over the remaining array using `map()`, which will return an array
3. Inside the `map()` loop, iterate over each value using `reduce()` to sum each element of the array

The first element is ignored using destructuring assignment/rest.  The `[_,...arr]` means the first element will be stored in a variable called `_`, the rest of the elements will be stored in an array called `arr`, which is elements 2..5 (index:1..4).

---

### Sum by Index

```js
let data = [
  [36, 1500, 2, 3, 4],
  [36, 15, 2, 7, 8],
  [99, 99, 99, 99, 99], // fake data
  [36, 3000, 4, 5, 6],
  [36, 8, 7, 6, 15]
]

// only pull records with 36 as value of first element
let filtered = data.filter(arr => arr[0] == 36)

// initialize array to hold sums
let sums = Array(filtered[0].length).fill(0)

// iterate over each array and each index to sum value at the index
filtered.forEach(([_, ...arr]) =>
  arr.forEach((val, ndx) =>
    sums[ndx] += +val
  )
)

console.log(sums)
```

1. Filter the data for what you want based on the first element (stored in `filtered`)
2. Initialize the holding array of `sums` by index to `0`
3. Iterate over the filtered array (rows) using `forEach`
4. Inside the `forEach()` loop, iterate over each value using another `forEach()` using the index and value to store to the `sums` array created earlier

The first element is ignored using destructuring assignment/rest.  The `[_,...arr]` means the first element will be stored in a variable called `_`, the rest of the elements will be stored in an array called `arr`, which is elements 2..n (index:1..n-1).

Comment: Your SUM by INDEX is exactly what I needed, Your code looks 100% cleaner then my hack job, thanks, I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you are trying to sum the arrays.

```js
const test1 = [[36,1500,2,3,4],[36,15,2,7,8],[36,3000,4,5,6],[36,8,7,6,15]];

const sum = arr => arr.reduce((total, item) => total + item, 0);

console.log(test1.reduce((total, arr) => sum(arr) + total, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the array to a new array of sums using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a sum of the child arrays. This will give an array of sums, if you would like a sum of those, you can then use reduce again on that result and get a final number.

```js
// Our starting data
let test1 = [[36,1500,2,3,4],[36,15,2,7,8],[36,3000,4,5,6],[36,8,7,6,15]]

// a simple reusable sum function
const sum = (sum, val) => sum + val

// Sum each array
let result = test1.map(arr => arr.reduce(sum, 0))

// Display the results (stringified for readability)
console.log('Each array sumed:', JSON.stringify(result))

// Sum the results if needed
console.log('Sum of all arrays:', result.reduce(sum, 0))
```

Comment: I was trying to create a new array that  would have the sum of array[0][0] + array[1][0] + array[2][0]. , then  get a sum of array[0][1] + array[1][1] + array[1][2] etc.. These answers made me look at map which is new to me as a GIS Web Developer..